# How to subset/sum by a variable number of columns in R

Tags: r

I'm currently in the process of designing what is essentially a maximization algorithm in R. What I'm trying to figure out is how to apply a "for each" and "subset by" (more accurately, "count/sum if") for an undefined number of variables (each in it's own column).

For my example below, I'm going to use a dataset with 3 variable columns (not counting the ID and Category variables, which are not part of the maximization process).

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

sample_data <- cbind(c(1:400), c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 200), rep(3, 140), rep(4, 40)),
                     randu[,1]*1000000+1, round(randu[,2]*100,0)+1, randu[,3])

colnames(sample_data) <- c("ID", "Category", "Dollar_Volume", "Count", "Percentage1")

percentiles <- matrix(seq(.01, 1, .01), ncol = 1)

for (c in 3:ncol(sample_data))
{

  percentiles <- cbind(percentiles,
                       matrix(round(quantile(sample_data[,c], seq(.01, 1, .01)), digits = 2), ncol = 1))

}

colnames(percentiles) <- c("Percentile", colnames(sample_data)[3:ncol(sample_data)])
```

So now what I want to do is basically get all the unique combinations of the percentiles I've calculated (e.g. (1st/1st/1st; 1st/1st/2nd; ...; 100th/100th/100th) for my N variables, and then do a check such that:

```
Ncount <- sum(sample_data[,c] >= PercentileN[,c]
         & sample_data[,c + 1] >= PercentileN[,c + 1]
         & ...
         & sample_data[,ncol(sample_data)] >= PercentileN[,ncol(sample_data)]
         )
```

This basically just checks how many of my "sample_data" rows are above the current percentile combination selected, for every possible combination of percentiles for N parameters.

Then this "Ncount" value, along with the related parameter percentile values used to generate that number, would be added to a table to be referenced later. There are additional steps later, but not relevant to where I'm stuck.

Essentially, my question boils down to how to do this last part - I don't know of a way to dynamically "subset" by a variable number of parameters.

Any help or ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Not quite sure what you're looking for but if you use `data.table`, you can subset by multiple conditions using `dt[condition1 & condition2 & condition 3..., .N]` where `dt` is your data.table and `.N` gives you the number of rows for the subset. If you want unique values, you could use `unique`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly here --- you can get all the possible combinations with `grid.expand`. Then, you could rather use vectorization to check if your sample data is greater for all rows. Per row of the combinations.

So first you check if the row-values are greater. Then you check if all the values are greater via `colSums == 3`

```
all_combs = t(expand.grid(percentiles[, 2], percentiles[, 3], percentiles[, 4]))

apply(sample_data[, 3:5], 1, function(x) sum(colSums(x >= all_combs) == 3))
```